# Horizontal Alignment in Photoshop - Which is correct?

Tags: alignment

I usually align two text within a box using "Horizontal align center" button at the top menu in Photoshop. Is it the right way to align a text horizontally, or should i measure pixel by pixel using a Marque tool to make it visually horizontal?

It visually appears to the user that it is not aligned center. But technically I am right. How will the UI developer measure it to align it in HTML? Will the user think the alignment is not centered even though it is technically right?

[image]

- The above picture is technically aligned centre.

[image]

- This image shows the manual alignment which is visually correct.

Which method should I use being an UX designer?

Please explain this to me with an example.

Comment: The top one is the right one, to me.  The bottom one looks **very** visually _incorrect_, not correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you don't 'visually' center it the way you explained it, but you use the preferred, default usage PS showed you. That said, it is a personal preference.

- If you have CAPITALS they don't center visually
- HTML headings that are inline don't center visually

---

### First example

On the wordpress homepage for example, they have these quotes:

[image]

They don't make the blue hyperlinks visually centered. That's because no browser does that, natively.

---

### another example

*another example* from the theme page:

[image]

Comment: Are Jobile and By FasterThemes manually aligned to bottom?

Comment: @Hemalatha No, that is the whole idea. This is the standard on the web. No need for workarounds.

Comment: @Hemalatha did this help you out?

Comment: Yes! This helps me. But i would like to know more scenarios to understand this much better. Can u share me urls or examples?